# Exporting release build - Flex through Intellij Idea

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea, flexbuilder, release-builds

How do I generate release build of my Flex Application
through IntelliJ Idea, like I do in Flex Builder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Right click on any project and select module setting.
2. Select tab "Flex compiler setting"
3. Last field on this tab is "Additional compiler options:"
     add "-debug=false" without double quotes to it.
4. Do this for all the subprojects.  (From this form only you can choose different projects).
5. do a project Rebuild and you will get a smaller swf.

Only problem is you need to keep separate project files for debug and release build, but thats ok, as you release builds are done rarely.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate answer:

Instead of creating a Flex Module, create a Java Module, and add 2 Flex Facet's to it. One facet will be configured as the debug facet, the other as the release facet. This process will create 2 swf files, debug and release versions.

1. Create a java module, for example "FlexHelloWorld". Do not add a flex facet yet.
2. In the project view, right click on the project and select module setting
3. Under the Modules option, select the "FlexHelloWorld" module
4. Click the "+" symbol, add Flex Facet
5. Rename facet to "Debug"
6. Enter your main class name
7. Enter "debug.swf" as the output file name
8. Click apply
9. Click the "+" symbol, add Flex Facet
10. Rename facet to "Release"
11. Enter your main class name
12. Enter "release.swf" as the output file name
13. Under additional compiler options, add "-debug=false -optimize=true"
14. Click ok
15. Build the module. In the output directory, you will have "debug.swf" and "release.swf" files.

Note: In your HTML wrapper, you will have to call either debug.swf or release.swf. Or you could create 2 wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

Does IntelliJ support Ant? Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but you could use the Flex Ant Tasks to build outside of FB.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_1.html